# Composite C1 - Image Compression

Tags: c1-cms

I have a Composite C1 site - a client is uploading photos to blog posts.

The photos are huge - 1.5MB. Is there a module to compress them (size & dimension wise)?

The crop module only crops & doesn't resize.

I have not found any such modules on Google. Thanks

UPDATE

I have added an aspect ratio - but it is greyed out (LPFF Preset Wide):

[image]

Comment: The greyed out option was because the aspect ratio (e.g. 800x600) was larger than the image I was trying to upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply resize an image (manually) already in the media archive:

1. Open it in the built-in Image Editor (in the Media perspective).
2. Image / Scale image... (or click the Scale button on the toolbar - 2nd from the left)

You can also crop the image in the same Image Editor:

1. Click the top button ("Select") on the floating bar. (The crop button on the toolbar will get enabled.)
2. Use the cursor to select an area on the image.
3. Click the crop button on the toolbar (3rd from the left)

Comment: Thanks. I paid $20 for a crop tool - was that un-necessary or i that the crop you're referring to?

Comment: The $20 module you are referring to gives you more control over cropping like using predefined cropping sets, saving cropped files as new files along with the original ones as well as controlling the compression ratio of JPEGs etc. I've referred to a built-in cropping function in the Image editor, which is very simplistic.

Comment: For some reason the aspect ratio I have added is greyed out - do you know why? I have updated the question

Comment: I solved this - the ratio I had used (500 x 200) was bigger than the input image. I changed it to 5x2 and it now works & isn't greyed out.

Comment: The Image Crop addon has a quick user manual http://www.composite.net/Add-on-Market/Packages/Composite.Media.ImageCrop/UserManual, as well as an extended user guide http://www.composite.net/Add-on-Market/Packages/Composite.Media.ImageCrop/UserManual/ImageCrop-User-Guide (also in PDF http://www.composite.net/media/9a349579-cc57-4c12-951f-ae461c3af3ff/-1904246114/Packages/Guides/Composite.Media.ImageCrop.User.Guide.pdf). The "no so obvious" :) nuances of the aspect ratio are described there.  Hope they would help, too

Comment: Thanks - I still have a problem. For example a user uploads a huge 4000x3000 image - I need 100x50. Even if you crop some of it out and lower to 80% compression - it is still way too big.

I need something that will shrink the actual dimensions. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a recent version of Composite C1 you can resize images you include in the Visual Editor either by pulling the corner of the image or invoking the image properties dialog and set a max width or height (advanced tab).

If you need a code centered fix you can append ?mw=100&mh=100 to the image URL and your image will be automatically resized.

In Composite C1 4.1 you can append ?q=80 to JPEG image URLs to have the web server do compression. The number controls the image quality (100 highest).

All these features are part of the standard open source product.

Comment: Thanks. Appending the ?q=80 is interesting - in most cases it is a user uploading the image, say for a blog post. Does it do the compression once, save it then pull the saved copy?

Having the option in the visual editor is also nice. What would be best is when a user uploads an image having it somehow auto compress / resize, rather than having to 'go back' and change it. Is that possible?

Comment: Thanks - I still have a problem. For example a user uploads a huge 4000x3000 image - I need 100x50. Even if you crop some of it out and lower to 80% compression - it is still way too big.

I need something that will shrink the actual dimensions. Is that possible?